# Display Dataset[Databin[]] as result for cloud deployed FormFunction

Tags: formatting, cloud-deploy, form-building

I am trying to set up a cloud deployed `FormFunction` where a user can enter a public databin ID and then view the contents formatted as a dataset. I keep running into issues where the output of the form returns straight text rather than the table I am looking for.

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[
   {
     "Databin ID:" -> <|
        "Help" -> "Enter the ID of a public Databin"
      , "Interpreter" -> "String"|>
    ,  ...
    }
  , Dataset[Databin[#"Databin ID:"]] &
  ]
, Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

And here is a snippet of what I am getting in return when I try to view the databin as a dataset:

```
Dataset[{<|"Name" -> "Ben", "Email" -> "fake@gmail.com","Timestamp" -> DateObject[{2018, 5, 18, 12, 26, 55.98299980163574}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -7.]|><|"Name" -> "bob", "Email" -> "anotherfake@gmail.com","Timestamp" ->  DateObject[{2018, 5, 18, 12, 30, 33.210999965667725}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -7.]|>.....
```

I can replace

```
Dataset[Databin[#"Databin ID:"]]&
```

with this

```
ExportForm[Dataset[Databin[#"Databin ID:"]], "PNG"] &
```

and it will display an image of what I am looking for, but any other formatting option (`"HTML", "WL"`, etc.) either fails or returns the same string of text as before

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Afaict `Dataset` does not have associated any fancy export options.** It is either an `InputForm` (1D input or what it evaluates too) or a `StandardForm` (grid interface).

Mathematica Notebooks by default generate `StandardForm` output so that it why it works there.

PNG, or any other raster/vector image formats are generated from the `StandardForm` so this is why you see expected images for those `ExportForms`.

**For WolframCloud's FrontEnd `StandardForm` is only supported in *cloud notebooks* or in `"CloudCDF"` `ExportForm`.** (not sure how exactly cdf and nb differ in cloud).

The default `ExportForm` in `FormFunction` is `CloudCDFElement` which converts evertyhing to html, except `Manipulate/DynamicModule` (guess based on observation). And `Dataset` exported to HTML is just a plain input form string as explained above.

**TL;DR;**: **Use `"CloudCDF"` for `FormFunction` export form or any other image format.**

Comment: Perfect.  By using `ExportForm[Dataset[Databin[#"Databin ID:"]], "CloudCDF"] &` as the output, it displayed the way I was looking for.  I had originally avoided the option because I thought it required the plugin (which it doesn't).