# How to create a form that takes user input (e.g., gmail address) and displays a dataset of that user data from Databin

Tags: cloud-deploy, datadrop

I am trying to deploy a form where a user can enter their information such as their ID or any identifier only pertaining to them and then view the corresponding contents formatted as a dataset.

A similar question was asked in here:
[Display Dataset[Databin[]] as result for cloud deployed FormFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175247/display-datasetdatabin-as-result-for-cloud-deployed-formfunction/266344#266344)

But his problem was slightly different as he wanted to view the contents formatted as a dataset when a user enters a public databin ID. In contrast, I want the form to return a dataset of the input from a given databin. For example, I have a dataset looking like this:
[image]

And I want to deploy a form that asks for `id` and returns the second row of the dataset when user enters `danay`.

I feel like I can refactor the following code from his post but I'm a beginner so I'm not sure how. Please help!

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{"Databin ID:" -> <|
     "Help" -> "Enter the ID of a public Databin", 
     "Interpreter" -> "String"|>, }, 
  ExportForm[Dataset[Databin[#"Databin ID:"]],"CloudCDF"] &], Permissions -> "Public"]
```